# How to pass MPI communicator handle from Fortran to C using iso_c_binding

Tags: c, fortran, mpi, fortran-iso-c-binding, fortran2003

I am trying to link a parallel MPI Fortran program to a parallel C library which uses MPI too. The software architecture is Fortran-centered so I'm trying to keep as much as I can on the Fortran side.

So I need to pass the C routines a handle to the MPI communicator. They are of the form

```
  int CFunction(int *something, MPI_Comm *Ccomm)
```

MPI comes with interfaces to translate a Fortran to a C communicator handle:

```
MPI_Comm MPI_Comm_f2c(MPI_Fint comm)
```

However, these routines are supposed to be called from C so right now I've had to add C wrapper functions I can pass the Fortran communicator to:

```
int CFunction_FMPI(int *something, MPI_Fint *Fcomm)
{   MPI_Comm Ccomm; int status;
    Ccomm = MPI_Comm_f2c(*Fcomm); // Convert Fortran->C communicator
    status = CFunction(*something,*Ccomm); // Call original function
    return status;
}
```

then I had to write a 2nd interface -- to `CFunction_FMPI` -- using Fortran's C bindings to allow it to be called from Fortran.

My question is: isn't there any better way to do this, i.e., to avoid the C wrapper with Fortran->C communicator conversion? I think calling `MPI_Comm_f2c` directly from Fortran and storing the result in a `type(c_ptr)` or `integer(c_int)` variable would be best, but I haven't been able to do it since there is no straightforward/general binding between the `MPI_Comm` type and Fortran.

Answer (score 4):

No, I don't think there is a much better way to do it. And it is not that much complicated that I would be concerned about it. You can look at a similar function I use at

https://github.com/LadaF/PoisFFT/blob/master/src/f_mpi_comm_c2f.c

It is the opposite direction to your `CFunction_FMPI` and just translates the communicator. It is from C to Fortran.

```
// This function is callable from Fortran. MPI_Comm_c2f itself may be just a macro.

MPI_Fint f_MPI_Comm_c2f(MPI_Comm *comm) {
  return MPI_Comm_c2f(*comm);
}
```

It is than called from Fortran as

```
interface
    integer function MPI_Comm_c2f(c_handle) bind(C, name="f_MPI_Comm_c2f")
      use iso_c_binding
      type(c_ptr), value :: c_handle
    end function
end interface
```

The important point is that `MPI_Comm_c2f` is in some MPI libraries a C macro, not a function, so you cannot really call it from Fortran. I am quite sure `MPI_Comm_f2c` is also allowed to be a macro and you cannot therefore call it from Fortran.

---

What you can do is to create a Fortran function, which just calls the C wrapper for `MPI_Comm_f2c` and than call your C function in Fortran using a `bind(C)` interface as

```
status = CFunction(something, c_comm)
```

and thus avoid creating a wrapper for each C function. You just need a Fortran interface block for them.

The problem is that you don't have `MPI_Comm` in Fortran* in (in practice it is a pointer or an int) so you must use an opaque pointer.

```
MPI_Comm* f_MPI_Comm_f2c(MPI_Fint Fcomm)
{   MPI_Comm* Ccomm;
    Ccomm = malloc(sizeof(MPI_Comm));
    *Ccomm = MPI_Comm_f2c(Fcomm);
    return Ccomm;
}
```

which returns an opaque pointer `type(c_ptr)`. (Check for potential C coding errors I just even forgot to use semicolons.)

You than just once convert the Fortran communicator to the pointer to the C communicator.

```
 type(c_ptr) :: c_comm
 c_comm = f_MPI_Comm_f2c(comm)
```

---

* There is a derived type `type(MPI_Comm)` in MPI-3, but it contains an integer component which must be converted by the conversion routines anyway.

Comment: Thanks @vladimir-f, your approach works very well. Actually, calling the `f_MPI_Comm_f2c` function just once in the code avoids boring allocations/deallocations of the C pointer. It would be great if Fortran provided an object-oriented encapsulation of MPI like C++...

Comment: Actually, the C++ MPI bindings are deprecated. The modern Fortran 2008 bindings are quite a nice step forward.

Comment: Yeah but usage of .mod files from the MPI implementation will always be compiler-dependent, isn't it? Since the .mod format has not been standardized as a corresponding C header would be

Comment: That's something else. C++ ABI also isn't compiler indempendent. If you are implying you are still using `mpif.h`, it really isn't a good idea. If the MPI is compiled for a different compiler you can still have unpleasant surprises even if you manage to compile.